# Get max value of similar items in array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have an array like this:

`["13rq8", "13rq6", "13rq4", "13rq2", "13dl", "12dl", "13rq12", "13rq10"]`

and I want to get a final array that will group similar values that changes from each other only by the last numbers of the string ("13rq8", "13rq6", "13rq4", "13rq2", "13rq12", "13rq10"), and return only the biggest values like the example below:

`["13dl", "12dl", "13rq12"]`

Can you help me please resolve this in Javascript?

Thank You!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to write the Javascript first, and then explain what problems you were having with your approach, and then someone will help you.

Comment: They don't change from each other only by the last numbers of the string but also the letter(s) in-between.

Comment: Why would you think that "13dl" and "12dl" are grater than say 13rq(x) ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object (ex. `tagNum`) to keep track of the largest value of each prefix, and use regular expression to extract the prefix and trailing value:

```js
var l = ["13rq8", "13rq6", "13rq4", "13rq2", "13dl", "12dl", "13rq12", "13rq10"];
var tagNum = {};

l.forEach(function(x) {
  var m = x.match(/^(.*?)(\d*)$/);
  var tag = m[1];
  var num = parseInt("0" + m[2]);
  if (tagNum[tag] === undefined || tagNum[tag] < num) tagNum[tag] = num;
});

var l2 = [];
for (var tag in tagNum) {
  var num = tagNum[tag];
  if (num) l2.push(tag + num);
  else l2.push(tag);
}

console.log(l2);
```

Comment: This returns two values for "13rq", not one. I think the OP's "last numbers" includes all the trailing digits, not just the last one and you probably should not assume they're in any particular order.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the insight. it has been corrected.

Comment: This is not working - I get error accessing property!

Comment: @BekimBacaj, that's strange. `Run code snippet` worked in both Chrome and Firefox for me

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You @Fabricator!

Comment: That was stackoverflows lack of support of my browser on a snippet, so it's OK cause works on console.